# iTextSharp - how to move section header to next page

Tags: itext

When running reports using iTextSharp we can keep all the sub categories together defining a separate PdfpTable and KeepTogether = True

This works really well with sub categories that are unlikely to go over a full page.

Is there a way to move the main categories to the next page if the sub ones do not fit on that current page?

This is what we are getting

[image]

Where Expenses starts at the end of the last main category, but the sub-categories are all on the next page

This is a snippet of how they are created...

Thanks

```
 vTable.AddCell(AddNewTextCell(True, "REVENUE", 15, ReportFontSize, False))
        vTable.AddCell(Spacer_Cell(10, 15))

        For Each Row As DataRow In RevenueData
            Dim vInnerTable As New PdfPTable(15)
            vInnerTable.KeepTogether = True

            Dim vCatID As Integer = Row("ID")
            vInnerTable.AddCell(AddNewTextCell(True, Row("Name"), 15, ReportFontSize, False))
            Dim vSelected() As DataRow = RevenueNomDT.Select("CatID = " & vCatID, "Position")



            For Each SubRow As DataRow In vSelected
                SetLeftPadding = 10
                vInnerTable.AddCell(AddNewTextCell(False, SubRow("NomCode") & " " & SubRow("NomName"), 2, ReportFontSize))
                Dim NomCode As Integer = SubRow("NomCode")
                Dim NegValue As Integer = SubRow("NegValue")
                Dim vNeg As Boolean = False
                If NegValue = 1 Then
                    vNeg = True
                End If
                Dim vNomType As Integer = 0
                Dim vTypes() As DataRow = NLCodes.Select("NL_Code = '" & NomCode & "'", Nothing)
                For Each NominalRow As DataRow In vTypes
                    vNomType = NominalRow("Account_Type")
                Next

                SetLeftPadding = 0
                '12 Columns of data
                For i As Integer = 0 To 11
                    Dim vNomValue As Decimal = 0
                    Dim ReportMonth As Integer = DateDiff(DateInterval.Month, ReportStartDate, ReportDate) + 1
                    If ReportMonth > i Then
                        If vNomType = 2 Then
                            vNomValue = ReturnMonthlyAmount(i, NomCode, True, ReportStartDate, ReportEndDate, Current_HOA_ID, vNeg)
                        Else
                            vNomValue = ReturnMonthlyAmount(i, NomCode, False, ReportStartDate, ReportEndDate, Current_HOA_ID, vNeg)
                        End If

                        RT += vNomValue
                        GT = DicRevenue.Item(i)
                        DicRevenue.Item(i) = GT + vNomValue
                        Dim vAmt As Decimal = DicSubs.Item(i)
                        DicSubs.Item(i) = vNomValue + vAmt

                        vInnerTable.AddCell(AddNewCurrencyCell(vNomValue, False, False, ReportFontSize))
                    Else
                        vInnerTable.AddCell(AddNewCurrencyCell(vNomValue, False, False, ReportFontSize))
                    End If
                Next
                vInnerTable.AddCell(AddNewCurrencyCell(RT, False, False, ReportFontSize))
                GT = DicRevenue(12)
                DicRevenue(12) = GT + RT
                DicSubs.Item(12) = RT
                RT = 0
            Next

            SetLeftPadding = 5

            'Add the total of each revenue sub header
            vInnerTable.AddCell(AddNewTextCell(True, "Total " & Row("Name"), 2, ReportFontSize, False))
            For i As Integer = 0 To 11
                vInnerTable.AddCell(AddNewCurrencyCell(DicSubs.Item(i), True, True, ReportFontSize, False))
                RT += DicSubs.Item(i)
            Next

            vInnerTable.AddCell(AddNewCurrencyCell(RT, True, True, ReportFontSize, False))
            vTable.AddCell(NoSplitTable(vInnerTable, 15))

            'Remove the DictionaryValues
            For i As Integer = 0 To 12
                DicSubs(i) = 0
            Next
            RT = 0
        Next

        vTable.AddCell(Spacer_Cell(10, 15))
        'Add in the Totals For Revenue
        vTable.AddCell(AddNewTextCell(True, "TOTAL REVENUE", 2, ReportFontSize, False))
        For i As Integer = 0 To 12
            vTable.AddCell(AddNewCurrencyCell(DicRevenue.Item(i), True, True, ReportFontSize, False))
        Next
        GT = 0
        RT = 0
        vTable.AddCell(Spacer_Cell(20, 15))

        '============================================START OF EXPENSES ==============================================
        vTable.AddCell(AddNewTextCell(True, "EXPENSES", 15, ReportFontSize, False))
        vTable.AddCell(Spacer_Cell(10, 15))


 Private Function NoSplitTable(TableName As PdfPTable, DataColumns As Integer) As PdfPCell
    Dim vCell As New iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPCell(TableName)
    Try
        With vCell
            .Border = 0
            .Colspan = DataColumns
        End With
        Return vCell
    Catch ex As Exception
        EmailError(ex)
        Return vCell
    End Try

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out simpler than I thought - just add subTables for each header as well

Start of one table

```
 Dim vRevenueTable As New PdfPTable(15)
        vRevenueTable.KeepTogether = True

        vRevenueTable.AddCell(AddNewTextCell(True, "REVENUE", 15, ReportFontSize, False))
        vRevenueTable.AddCell(Spacer_Cell(10, 15))
        For Each Row As DataRow In RevenueData
            Dim vInnerTable As New PdfPTable(15)
            vInnerTable.KeepTogether = True
```

.... end of that table

```
vInnerTable.AddCell(AddNewCurrencyCell(RT, True, True, ReportFontSize, False))
            vRevenueTable.AddCell(NoSplitTable(vInnerTable, 15))

            'Remove the DictionaryValues
            For i As Integer = 0 To 12
                DicSubs(i) = 0
            Next
            RT = 0
        Next
        vRevenueTable.AddCell(Spacer_Cell(10, 15))
        'Add in the Totals For Revenue
        vRevenueTable.AddCell(AddNewTextCell(True, "TOTAL REVENUE", 2, ReportFontSize, False))
        For i As Integer = 0 To 12
            vRevenueTable.AddCell(AddNewCurrencyCell(DicRevenue.Item(i), True, True, ReportFontSize, False))
        Next
        GT = 0
        RT = 0
        vRevenueTable.AddCell(Spacer_Cell(20, 15))

        vTable.AddCell(NoSplitTable(vRevenueTable, 15))
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides using keeptogether-tables you can force page breaks by calling
Document.NewPage() or wrap your tables with Chapters and Sections instead of creating one big table container.
(4.1.6.0)

Comment: The problem with Document.NewPage is.. 1 - It's a different method to Table.Add and in this function it's just returning a table to a multi-page document with headers and footers - 2 - There is no way of knowing how many lines are going to be produced so a new page could be added one line after the last one started

Comment: Yeah, thats the pain with automatically generating documents from dynamic data :D